# How to find the amount of times a specific pair occurs in a dataset

Tags: python, dataset

I have the following task: I have a dataset that has the following attributes (UserID, ZipCode, Datetime) which are all in a csv file saved as strings. What I need to do is find daily transitions of a user-id from one zip to another. So far I know I would have to detect if a user moves within a pair of zips. However, this also depends on the time. This means if user moves from point a to point b and then to point c in the same day then the pairs would be (a,b) and (b,c). If the same user moves between the same pair in the same day it only counts once. This also is restricted by month meaning that if a transition occurs between a pair the counter gets incremented for that specific pair for that month. I am doing this on python, any feedback that would point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
Data set example (it contains thousands of similar records:
UserID=4352343
ZipCode=12345
DateTime=2/18/2020 20:32
```

The new file is also a csv file with the following parameters month,year,zip1,zip2,number of transitions for each record.

Comment: I don't have any experience with a dataset like this (I use json for data), so I am most likely wrong on this (thats why im posting it as a comment), so maybe you could iterate through your dataset, and store whenever a pair comes up in your data set so you could see how many times it is in your data set. (sorry idk how else to word it, and this is probably wrong)

Comment: I appreciate any help and yes I had a hard time writing my question too. I understand what you mean as that is my first approach but I am stuck finding how to figure out timings as described. And the new folder is also going to be a csv file with the parameters  month,year,zip1,zip2,number of transitions

Comment: is the csv file sorted by columns? 
E.g.
`UserID, ZipCode, DateTime\n4352343, 12345, 2/18/2020 20:32` ?

Comment: The columns have the following order UserID, ZipCode, Unixtimestamp, DateTime (2/18/20 20:32). I converted all unix timestamps to readable dates that is why I only included it.